# Two Variable First Order Approximation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, approximation, algebra

I found that using Series and Normal command, I am able to approximate the first order of x or y, but If I also get rid of x*y (cross term), Series command does not work any more.

Let's define some arbitrary function for example.

```
f = 1/x + (x^2 y + 1)/(2 + x + x^2) + (y^2 + x)/x^2 + (x y + 1)/x^2
```

### **Series command**

If I use Series function,

```
Series[Series[f, {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}] // Normal // Together
```

This will give me

```
(4 + 8 x + 2 x^2 - x^3 + 4 x y)/(4 x^2)
```

But I still have cross term but series command cannot get rid of cross term.

```
Series[%, {x*y, 0, 0}] // Normal // Together
```

Which does not know that it is cross term, and also I still have 2nd order

```
(4 + 8 x + 2 x^2 - x^3 + 4 x y)/(4 x^2)
```

*By hand*

```
(4 + 8 x )/(4 x^2)
=> 1/x^2 + 2/x
```

### **Ideal Result**

Here is what I want to get, which results quite differently with previous approach.

```
Together[f]
```

This will give me

```
 (2 + 5 x + 4 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 2 x y + x^2 y + x^3 y + x^4 y + 2 y^2 + 
 x y^2 + x^2 y^2)/(x^2 (2 + x + x^2))
```

Get rid of all the higher order term of x and y and cross term (Since the Denominator expands to 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4, So I get rid of all the higher order so it will become 2 x^2,)

*By hand*

```
(2 + 5 x)/(2 x^2)

=> 1/x^2 + 5/(2 x)
```

So I have two question

1. Why do I get different answer?
2. How to do *by hand* part in MMA?

Comment: How did you use `Series` - you're not explaining what you tried, i.e., the code using `Series` that you said doesn't work. What are the small variables? Just `x`, or also `y`, or some combination of them? Are you expanding around zero?

Comment: I cannot figure out what is the desired result.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clear.  I am sorry for confusing question. @DanielLichtblau

Comment: I modified the question to make it clear.  I am sorry for confusing question. @Jens

Comment: what happend to the `2*y^2` part in the numerator? From your desired result, I guess that you want to neglect it because its exponent (2) is larger than the smallest non-zero exponent belonging to `x` (1)? I do not have time to answer right now, will do that later if noone else does in the meantime. As a start for you: To get rid of crossterms, consider this: `term/.x^(n___:1)*y^(n___:1)->0` where `term` is some polynomial.

Comment: @Lukas  Since the Denominator x^2 (2 + x + x^2), when I expand it, it will be 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4, So I get rid of all the higher order so it will become 2 x^2, I edit the post! Thank you!

Comment: No I mean the numerator. The “upper“ part of your fraction. There is a 2y^2 term not involved into crossterms. It just disappears, although it is (apart from constant) the lowest order in y

Comment: @Lukas Ah, because y^2 is also higher than y, so I only keep until the first order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your "by hand" math is wrong. Here is what you get when doing a consistent first-order expansion:

```
expr = (2 + 5 x + 4 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 2 x y + x^2 y + x^3 y + 
    x^4 y + 2 y^2 + x y^2 + x^2 y^2)/(x^2 (2 + x + x^2));

Normal[
  Series[expr /. {x -> ϵ x, y -> ϵ y}, {ϵ, 0, 1}]] /. ϵ -> 1
```

> $$\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x}-\frac{x}{4}+\frac
>    {2}{x}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when I combine together, (4 + 8 x + 2 x^2 - x^3 + 4 x y + 4 y^2)/(4 x^2) I still have cross term. and second order on top.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I guess I can just separate , numerator and denaminator again and do the series